# High IO> on EVERYTHING when trying to load games

Tags: games, iowait, iotop

So I'm new to Ubuntu and whenever I try to load a game (so far it's happened with any Linux game that I've tried) it goes fine for a bit, then the computer starts freezing up and I can't do anything. Watching iotop while this happens the IO> on almost everything shoots up to 99.99%. I've tried everything I can think of and what I could find on Google to solve this and nothing seems to help. It's not the HDD because I've tried on two seperate HDD's one that I know for a fact is good. The games I'm trying also run fine on Windows. Does anybody know what could be the cause of this, or how to solve it?